# How to show gif in npm package's readme file?

Tags: github, npm, gif, readme, npm-package

I have added below line in my Readme file and it works fine on GitHub but the gif is not showing on npm package page.

```
![@bilal111996/react-range-slider horizontal](https://github.com/bilalyaqoob/react-range-slider/blob/master/horizontal.gif)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the image link in your README with the '**raw**' link (i.e. the link to the actual image).
The link you used actually loads an HTML page with info of the GIF as a repository object on GitHub.
This causes [CORS errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors#:%7E:text=If%20the%20CORS%20configuration%20isn,violating%20the%20CORS%20security%20rules.) on NPM.

You have two options:

1. **Add `raw=true` to the end of the URL**:
   https://github.com/bilalyaqoob/react-range-slider/blob/master/horizontal.gif?raw=true
2. Use the direct raw URL:
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bilalyaqoob/react-range-slider/master/horizontal.gif

   *Note: To find this link:*

   - *open the link from 1. in your browser; it redirects to 2.*
   - *right-click the image and select 'Copy image address'*

Comment: not working for me